# There is an incorrect sass definition in quasar

Tags: quasar-framework

I try to run the application and get the following error,
-error 500-

App • ⚠️   Warmup failed!
Error: Undefined function.
╷
45 │   $rad: math.div($angle, 180) * $PI
│         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 45:9     sin()
node_modules\quasar\dist\quasar.sass 4598:16  root stylesheet

I tried to upgrade my quasar but it still dont work..

i tried to update my quasar but it still dont work..:-([enter image description here] with this command "yarn add -D rollup-plugin-sass-migrator sass-migrator"

and with this to " yarn global add @quasar/cli" whitout success.

img -
[URL=http://www.uploads.co.il/][IMG]http://www.uploads.co.il/uploads/images/321814314.png[/IMG][/URL]

The application run